# Performance of Laravel storage streaming file from Digital ocean spaces

Tags: php, laravel, digital-ocean

I've obtained the following code from searching about the topic

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    //disable execution time limit when downloading a big file.
    set_time_limit(0);

    $fs = Storage::disk('local');

    $path = 'uploads/user-1/1653600850867.mp3';

    $stream = $fs->readStream($path);

    if (ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();

    return response()->stream(function () use ($stream) {
        fpassthru($stream);
    },
        200,
        [
            'Accept-Ranges' => 'bytes',
            'Content-Length' => 14098560,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
        ]);
});
```

However when I click play on the UI, it takes a good four seconds to start playing. If I switch the disk to local though, it plays almost instantly.

Is there a way to improve the performance or, read the stream by range as per request?

### Edit

My current DO config is as per below

```
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('DO_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('DO_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('DO_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('DO_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('DO_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('DO_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('DO_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
```

But I find two type of integration online one specifying the CDN endpoint and one doesn't. I am not sure which one is relevant, though the one that specifies CDN is for Laravel 8 and I am on Laravel 9.

Comment: so you think it's network related? then try to use CDN

Comment: I tried enabling CDN and configured a sub domain but not sure if I am supposed to alter anything in Laravel. I found two examples of integrating DO, one specifies the CDN endpoint, and one doesn't.

Comment: Just enabling it at least doesn't seem lead to any improvements. It still takes four seconds to start.

Comment: I made another test where I moved the track to 7 minutes, then pressed play and observed the request taking at least 50 seconds to load. It's almost as if it tried to load the whole file prior to playing. Ideally I was hoping the code above achieves chunk playing similar to how videos buffer. I suspect the code ```readStream``` is where it's doing wrong?

Comment: you might need to profile your Laravel code if you still believe that problem is not network-related, try to trace from the moment your controller received request until chunk is ready to be sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change my code such that:

1. I had to use the php SDK client for connecting to Aws for the Laravel API isn't flexible to allow passing additional arguments (at least I haven't found anything while researching)
2. Change to streamDownload as I can't see any description to the stream method in the docs despite that it is present in code.

So the below code allows to achieve what I was aiming for which is, download by chunk based on the range received in the request.

```
    return response()->streamDownload(function(){
        $client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region'  =>  config('filesystems.disks.do.region'),
            'endpoint' =>  config('filesystems.disks.do.endpoint'),
            'credentials' => [
                'key'    => config('filesystems.disks.do.key'),
                'secret' => config('filesystems.disks.do.secret'),
            ],
        ]);

        $path = 'uploads/user-1/1653600850867.mp3';

        $range = request()->header('Range');

        $result = $client->getObject([
            'Bucket' => 'wyxos-streaming',
            'Key' => $path,
            'Range' => $range
        ]);

        echo $result['Body'];
    },
        200,
        [
            'Accept-Ranges' => 'bytes',
            'Content-Length' => 14098560,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
        ]);
```

Note:

- In a live scenario, you would need to cater for if range isn't specified, the content length will need to be the actual file size
- When range is present however, the content length should then be the size of the segment being echoed